# Changing Number of Products Per Row

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalog

I found lots of discussion regarding the issue. And the major solution for the issue is adding the line `<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>5</columns></action>` at the `catalog.xml`. I tried this, by writing the following code at local.xml,

```
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>5</columns></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>2</columns></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

At `app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` , i have added the following code for checking the number of columns,

```
$_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();
    var_dump($_columnCount);
```

It given `int(5)` at the main site. But the products per row is not changing. I am using `1column.phtml` for category page.
catalog.xml,

```
 <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>

       <reference name="left_first">

            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
            </block>
        </reference>


        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.after" as="after" />
                    <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                    <!-- Since the addColumnCountLayoutDepend does not work, we are manually setting the max columns -->
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
```

list.phtml:

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = 5; ?>

    <ul class="products-grid row products-grid-max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php $i++; /*if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
            <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-mobile-12 item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <div class="category-products-grid">

                    <div class="images-container">
                            <?php echo $helpLabels->getLabels($_product); //Product labels ?>
                            <?php //var_dump($_product); ?>
                             <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image quickview">
                                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($width , $height); ?>" width="<?php echo $width ?>" height="<?php echo $height ?>"
                                     alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                             </a>
                             <div class="link-view"> 
                                <a title="<?php echo $this->__('Quick View') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('magicshop/quickview/view') .'id/'.$_product->getId()?>" class="link-quickview"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><?php //echo $this->__('Quick View') ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <div class="actions-no">
                            <div class="actions">
                                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <ul class="add-to-links">
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                        <li class=""><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><i class="fa fa fa-heart-o"></i><?php //echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                        <li class=""><a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><i class="fa fa-signal"></i><?php //echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="product-info products-textlink clearfix">
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                        <?php
                        // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                        // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                        if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                                echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php /*if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
```

I hope someone will help on this issue,
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

in list.phtml under grid use below mention code

```
<?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
   <?php $_columnCount = 5; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Manoj kothari, No change

Comment: send me list.phtml code

Comment: see my edited question @Manoj kotari, I added list.phtml grid functions

Comment: hey you are using boostrub  <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-mobile-12 item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">

Comment: You jus change based on screen resolvation

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me go to 
app/design/frontend/your theme/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

add

```
else
{
    $_columnCount = 3; 
}  

<?php // Grid Mode ?>

<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>

<?php $_columnCount = Mage::getStoreConfig('ovansport_cfg/general/Count_colunm_listing');
if($_GET['prorow']) {
    $_columnCount=$_GET['prorow'];
} else {
    $_columnCount = 3; 
}
```